# Display text on a quad (or cube) in Unity3D for 2D game

Tags: text, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have the feeling this must be very easy thing to do but I can't find any answer.

I'm doing a small 2D puzzle game in Unity3D and I want to show some rectangles in a 2D space and each of those rectangles have a letter in them.

How do I do this in Unity3D? I tried to make a TextMesh and put it in front of the rectangles, but 1. The text looks awfully rendered, 2. I can't find a way to centre the text with the centre of the rectangle.

I'm doing this as 2D as possible so perhaps there is an easier (and better way to do it). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried putting a UI Canvas on the rectangle and then rendering text on there? (So normal GUI rendering in 3D space)

Comment: @BlueHat Thank you. The UI Text does indeed look better, problem is, it's not rendered in relation to the quad/cube but in a set position in space even if I make it a child of the quad/cube.

Comment: Well, we can have different approach based on your game. Does the triangle rotates? And if it does, does the text rotates with the Triangles?
Just need to ask this question so we can give you a specific answer based on your needs.

Comment: @Aizen Hi and thank you. They are quads and yes, they rotate and they also move around and the text always follows them in all movement like they are part of the quad.

Comment: @jbssm try this http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html to show you how to render is world space.

Answer (score 0):

Texture mapping is the easy way to do what you are describing. 
Download gimp or paint.net and create images that look the way you want, then texture map them to a plane.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html

Comment: But this way - correct me if I'm wrong - I can't have text in the quads changing, right? Imagine I wanted to change the letter the quad is displaying, this way I would have to load a new texture with a different letter right?

Comment: That's right. My understanding of your question is that you do not have enough control with TextMesh. Because of that your best bet is texture maps.